# Grab image URL inside href using Xpath

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

I want to grab all images inside href attributes from code above

```
<div class="jcarousel product-imagethumb-alt" data-jcarousel="true">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="https://domain/imagefull.jpg" onclick="return false;" class="cboxElement">
<img itemprop="image" src="http://domain/imagethumb.jpg"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I was try to grab it using code likes `div/ul/li//a[img]/@href` and `div/ul/li//a[@class="cboxElement"]/@href` also `div/ul/li//a/@href`, but no one images inside href grabbed.

Maybe someone can help to give me the best XPath expression to grab the images inside href.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `div/ul/li//a[img]/@href` or `//div/ul/li//a[img]/@href`?

Comment: Yes i was try it, but I still can't grab images on href

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the problem but with the following code I am able to grab the src of the image. The xpath is simply: //a/img

```
var anchors = document.evaluate("//a/img", 
    document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
var a = anchors.iterateNext(); 
while (a) {
  console.log(a.src);
  a = anchors.iterateNext();
}
```

You can see it also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hb3zfqr/)

Comment: Wow thanks for the snippets. I will try to test using your javascript code